# Combining Linq Expressions for Dto Selector

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

We have a lot of Dto classes in our project and on various occasions SELECT them using Expressions from the entity framework context. This has the benefit, that EF can parse our request, and build a nice SQL statement out of it.

Unfortunatly, this has led to very big Expressions, because we have no way of combining them.

So if you have a class DtoA with 3 properties, and one of them is of class DtoB with 5 properties, and again one of those is of class DtoC with 10 properties, you would have to write one big selector.

```
public static Expression<Func<ClassA, DtoA>> ToDto =
        from => new DtoA
        {
            Id = from.Id,
            Name = from.Name,
            Size = from.Size,
            MyB = new DtoB
            {
               Id = from.MyB.Id,
               ...
               MyCList = from.MyCList.Select(myC => new DtoC
                   {
                      Id = myC.Id,
                      ...
                   }
            }
        };
```

Also, they cannot be reused. When you have DtoD, which also has a propertiy of class DtoB, you would have to paste in the desired code of DtoB and DtoC again.

```
public static Expression<Func<ClassD, DtoD>> ToDto =
        from => new DtoD
        {
            Id = from.Id,
            Length = from.Length,
            MyB = new DtoB
            {
               Id = from.MyB.Id,
               ...
               MyCList = from.MyCList.Select(myC => new DtoC
                   {
                      Id = myC.Id,
                      ...
                   }
            }
        };
```

So this will escalate pretty fast. Please note that the mentioned code is just an example, but you get the idea.

I would like to define an expression for each class and then combine them as required, as well as EF still be able to parse it and generate the SQL statement so to not lose the performance improvement.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any abstraction for your classes and dtos? Maybe you could implement a generic method to create the expression.

Comment: What abstraction do you need? It is safe to assume, for this example, that dto and class are identical. I am not sure how i would implement the generic method. I don't want to lose the EF capability to parse an expression and build a sql expression based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) ? You can define your Dtos and create a mapping between the original entity and the Dto and/or vice versa, and using the projection, you don't need any select statements as Automapper will do it for you automatically and it will project only the dto's properties into SQL query.

for example, if you have a Person table with the following structure:

```
public class Person
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string Initial { get; set; }
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }
        public string FormerTitle { get; set; }
        public string FormerFamilyName { get; set; }
        public string FormerGivenName { get; set; }
}
```

and your dto was like this :

```
public class PersonDto
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FamilyName { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a mapping between Person and PersonDto like this

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>()
```

and when you query the database using Entity Framework (for example), you can use something like this to get PersonDto columns only:

```
ctx.People.Where(p=> p.FamilyName.Contains("John")) 
                .Project()
                .To<PersonDto>()
                .ToList();
```

which will return a list of PersonDtos that has a family name contains "John", and if you run a sql profiler for example you will see that only the PersonDto columns were selected.

Automapper also supports hierachy, if your Person for example has an Address linked to it that you want to return AddressDto for it.

I think it worth to have a look and check it, it cleans a lot of the mess that manual mapping requires.

Comment: I didnt know Automapper could do that! I dont think i will introduce it into this project, because that would mean introducing another dependency and we are almost done. I would also rather like to know how one would do it by hand, out of interest. Still a good heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a little, and I didn't come up with any "awesome" solution.

Essentially you have two general choices here,

1. Use placeholder and rewrite expression tree entirely.

Something like this,

```
public static Expression<Func<ClassA, DtoA>> DtoExpression{
    get{
        Expression<Func<ClassA, DtoA>> dtoExpression =  classA => new DtoA(){
            BDto = Magic.Swap(ClassB.DtoExpression),
        };

        // todo; here you have access to dtoExpression,
        // you need to use expression transformers
        // in order to find & replace the Magic.Swap(..) call with the
        // actual Expression code(NewExpression),
        // Rewriting the expression tree is no easy task,
        // but EF will be able to understand it this way.

        // the code will be quite tricky, but can be solved
        // within ~50-100 lines of code, I expect.
        // For that, see ExpressionVisitor.

        // As ExpressionVisitor detects the usage of Magic.Swap,
        // it has to check the actual expression(ClassB.DtoExpression),
        // and rebuild it as MemberInitExpression & NewExpression,
        // and the bindings have to be mapped to correct places.

        return Magic.Rebuild(dtoExpression);
    }
```

2. The other way is to start using only `Expression` class(ditching the LINQ). This way you can write the queries from zero, and reusability will be nice, however, things get harder & you lose type safety. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb882637.aspx) has nice reference about dynamic expressions. If you structure everything that way, you can reuse a lot of the functionality. Eg, you define `NewExpression` and then you can later reuse it, if needed.
3. The third way is to basically use lambda syntax:  `.Where`, `.Select` etc.. This gives you definitely better "reusability" rate. It doesn't solve your problem 100%, but it can help you to compose queries a bit better. For example: `from.MyCList.Select(dtoCSelector)`

Comment: Would i use the expression functionality of EF with version 1 though? I am not sure if "Magic.Swap" would be interpreted correctly by EF. Could you elaborate on 2 maybe with a code snippet?